# How to allow submission of empty string in django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My model is set up like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And my form like this:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment = forms.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ("comment")
```

Right now the form can be submitted when the comment field is empty, and when displaying on a different page, it will show as an empty string. I want comment to be saved as an empty string when the form is submitted with that field empty.

For example: I save form with "example comment" in the comment field. "example comment" is then saved to that Example object. Then I go back to the form with the instance as the previous Example object. Initially the comment field is filled in as "example comment". I want to delete that comment and save so that the comment is now saved as "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to do a little manual work, like this:

```
# in the views.py
if form.is_valid():
    new_example = form.save(commit=False)
    if not form.cleaned_data['comment']:
      new_example.comment = ""
      new_example.save()
```

Comment: I got this to work by changing `if not new_example.comment:` to `if not form.cleaned_data["comment"]:`.  Thanks